# Multi tenant EF implementation w/ Stored Procedures

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Greetings!

I'm using SPROCs within Entity Framework for all of my CRUD methods. Because this is a multi-tenant database, we have a clientID field in each of the tables. Our DBA doesn't want that clientID exposed, so we pass a username into the SPROC (username of authenticated user, tracked in the membership provider), which then handles conversion of username to clientID internally within sproc.

The issue I'm having is that my Entities don't have the Username property. When I create my function imports for insert/update/delete, the mapping is requesting a Username field (required, from my SPROC) which doesn't exist in my entity.  Here's my schema:

**Account Entity**

AccountNumber
AccountDescription
ClientID
ActiveFlag
RowVersion (for concurrency)

And my SPROC:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetAccounts]
@Username   varchar (60)
AS

/*********************************************
Summary:  Get Accounts
2011-01-20 aca  initial version
2011-01-27 aca  Alias for Description
2011-03-21 aca  Implement user security
********************************************/
select  P.FERC_ACCOUNT,
    P.[DESCRIPTION] as AccountDescription,
    P.RowVersion
from    dbo.P_ACCOUNTS P
join    dbo.v_UserClient U
on  U.Username = @Username
and P.CLIENT_ID = U.Client_ID
where   P.ActiveFlag = 1;

RETURN 0;
```

I'm not sure what the best way to proceed is. Do I just create a Username property in my entity? That means I'd have to do this on every one? How do I populate it? Etc etc :)

Thanks for your help!

Scott

Comment: Can you add it via partial class?

Comment: I certainly know what a partial class is (my domain service is broken out into one partial class per entity set, to accommodate updating my model and then not having to update all 200 methods that will make up my ds), but can u explain more how I'd implement and why?

Comment: Is this a SL project?  Are you mapping entities to procs or are you calling the exported functions directly.

Comment: Yeah, SL4, C#, MVVM-Light. I've got an entity, which is my Account table, and it has simply AccountNumber, AccountDescription, clientID. I then map my insert/update/delete sprocs to that entity. Its during this mapping process that I run into the requirement to map the sproc username field to the account entity. I also have a GetAccounts sproc that I imagine I'll have to call directly in my GetAccounts() method created by my domainservice.

Comment: I'd probably create an poco entity that represents what the stored procedure requires and pass one or a list into the exported DomainService funtion.

Comment: I'm pretty new to EF/WCF RIA (4 wks or so), created a demo app for my company (using actual db), but this is my first prod attempt. Any chance you can Answer my question with an example? I'm not a total noob, but the more handholding you can do, the happier I will be :)

Comment: Do you have select/insert/update access at all or are you restricted to doing everything through procs?

Comment: Everything has to be done via procs, unfortunately. At some point I hope to lay out a secure plan for EF with direct table access, but I'm just not there yet.

Comment: Let me know if you have more questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same restrictions and I export the stored procedures as functions.  For procedures that do not have output parameters I return the default generated complex type i.e. GetAccountsResult.

```
public IEnumerable<GetAccountsResult> GetAccounts(string username)
{
    return ObjectContext.GetAccounts(username).AsQueryable();
}
```

The complex type needs to have a property designated as the [Key].  To set the key for complextypes I create a partial for my domain service and use a buddy class to set the key.  So for AccountsDomainService.cs I create AccountsDomainService.metadata.cs.

```
[MetadataType(typeof(GetAccountsResultMetadata))]
    public partial class GetAccountsResult
{
    internal sealed class GetAccountsResultMetadata
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }
}
```

For procedures that do have output parameters I create a poco object containing properties for the output parameters and another poco object matching the complex type.  I then use AutoMapper to map the returned complex type to my created complex type.  I do this so I can return the relation.

Account.cs

```
 public class Account
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string MyOutputParameter { get; set; }

        [Include, Association("Account_AccountDetails", "Id", "AccountId")]
        public List<AccountDetail> AccountDetails { get; set; }
    }
```

AccountDetail.cs

```
    public class AccountDetail
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int AccountId { get; set; }
        public string MyAccountDetailProperty { get; set; }
    }
```

AccountDomainService.cs

```
 public Account GetAccountsWithOutputParms(string username)
        {
            var myOutputParameter = new ObjectParameter("MyOutPutParameter", typeof(int));

            var tempGetAccountsResult = ObjectContext.GetAccounts(username).ToList();

            var account = new Account
                              {
                                  Id = 1,
                                  MyOutputParameter = myOutputParameter,
                                  AccountDetails = Mapper.Map<List<GetAccountsResult>, List<AccountDetail>>(tempGetAccountsResult)
                              };

            return accout;
        }
```

When I get those results on the client, I use AutoMapper to map them to client side view models.

[This](http://thegrayzone.co.uk/blog/tag/wcf-ria-services/) article Stored Procedures with EF 4 and RIA Services is handy.

For insert/update you can create a poco object that models the procedure parameters and pass it to your exported function in your domain service.

Comment: This certainly sounds like the right answer, so I'm going to mark it as such. The site from that link is down, and I basically had until this morning to either move forward with EF, or not. I haven't used AutoMapper before, and I'd have to do some more research to understand some of the things you said to do, which I simply don't have time for. I appreciate your help... when I have some more bandwidth, I'll definitely revisit this question. Thanks Derek.

Comment: AutoMapper isn't a must.  You can map one object to another without it.  If you have more questions we could take it to emails. derek.beattie at gmail.

Comment: Its still down for me, perhaps its a firewall or some proxy at work. I'll take a look tonight at home. I'll shoot you an e-mail at some point too, thank you. I'd love to figure this out - writing asmx web services with server side models, db access layers, and client side models/services gets old fast. Thanks for your help.